# Django Template Tag Conditional

Tags: django, django-templates

How make a a conditional statement out of a **Django Template Tag**?

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def is_designer(user_id):
    try:
        group = Group.objects.get(
            name = "Designer",
            user = user_id
        )
        return True
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

This appears True or False in my template which is correct:

```
{% is_designer user.id %}
```

However these gives me an error "**Unused 'user.id' at end of if expression.**":

> {% if is_designer user.id == True %} Yes {% endif %}
>
> {% if is_designer user.id %} Yes {% endif %}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you made that into an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), you could do something like

```
{% is_designer user.id as is_user_designer %}

{% if is_user_designer == True %} Yes {% endif %}

{% if is_user_designer %} Yes {% endif %}
```

**Note:** As of Django 1.9, assignment tags are deprecated and simple tags can store values now. See the deprecation notice in the 1.9 docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags

Comment: Thanks this works, but I went with a filter instead: `{% if user|is_maker  %}
YES
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
{% is_designer user.id as is_user_designer %}
{{ is_user_designer|yesno:"Yes," }}
```